# Finding $k$ for which $\dfrac{x+2}{kx-1} = x$ has only one solution for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $\dfrac{x+2}{kx-1} = x$, compute the value of $k$ which there is only one solution for $x$.

I tried setting the discriminant of $kx^2 -2x -2$  to $0$, but solving $k$ as $-1/2$ makes zero solutions.

Comment: Do you mean “only **one** solution for $x$?”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, I changed it

Comment: You have the right $k.$ The problem is, the only $k$ where the quadratic has exactly one root has $kx_0-1=0$ when $x_0$ is that root. So there is no such $k.$

Comment: The question may have thought $k=-\frac12$ makes $x=-2$ but substituting to check leads to $\frac00=-2$

Comment: Oh, there is one other $k$ to try, because $kx^2-2x-2=0$ is not always a quadratic equation.

Comment: Well, if $k=-1/2$, then $$\dfrac{x+2}{-0.5 x-1}=\dfrac{x+2}{-0.5(x+2)}=-2$$ which converts this equation into $x=-2$, and this is the case you want.

Comment: The function can actually be continuously extended to the point where the problem exist, but I'm not sure if this is allowed in your question. (I'm talking about the limit.)

Comment: When $x=-2,$ $$\frac{x+2}{-\frac12x-1}=\frac00$$ @Kevin.S

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is true, but I'm talking about the fact that the function can be continuously extended to -2 so that it has a root. However, I personally think this kind of deliberate effort to make the question sensible is kind of ......... but I know that a lot of highschool material do not care about these kind of issues of the denominator, which is quite awkward....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just when k=0  there is only one solution for x,
Otherwise, the quadratic function should have two solutions.

Comment: Well, the quadratic has one solution sometimes, but the function is ill-defined for that $k.$